# I am having Trouble to get list of Categories of Custom post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I am using WordPress. Creating Custom theme. All Gone Perfect but i am having issue while calling all categories of my Custom post type.

Here are my codes.
in `functions.php`Codes are these.

```
function product() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Products', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Product', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Product' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Product' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Product' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Products' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Product' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Products' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No products found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No products found in the Trash' ), 
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Products'
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'description'   => 'Holds our products and product specific data',
    'public'        => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'menu_position' => 25,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-cart',
    'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
    'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
    'has_archive'   => false,
  );
  register_post_type( 'product', $args ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'product' );

function product_categories() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Product Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Product Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Product Categories' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Product Categories' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Product Category' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Product Category:' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Product Category' ), 
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Product Category' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Product Category' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Product Category' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Product Categories' ),
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
  );
  register_taxonomy( 'product_category', 'product', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'product_categories', 0 );
```

Now I wish to get all the Categories i have added in Product Post type.

But I am failed. I tried many ways but Some ways get Simple Default post's categories Not The Product Post.

Like here the codes

```
<?php
$args = array(
                    'post_type'          => 'product' ,
                    'show_option_all'    => '',
                    'orderby'            => 'name',
                    'order'              => 'ASC',
                    'style'              => 'list',
                    'show_count'         => 0,
                    'hide_empty'         => 0,
                    'use_desc_for_title' => 0,
                    'show_option_none'   => __( '' ),
                    'number'             => null,
                    'echo'               => 1,
                    'depth'              => 2,
                    'taxonomy'           => 'category',
                    'title_li'           => ''
                );
                wp_list_categories( $args );

?>
```

These codes show Default Post's Category Not Showing Product's Categories. What to do now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use get_terms function
[reference & examples here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

taxonomy name is your category name, product_category